# How to map entity items list in multiple Entities using @OneToMany annotation unidirectional?

Tags: spring, boot

Exception:
could not execute statement [Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (demodbdev.entityimage, CONSTRAINT FKcdf6ngpc2Sr30p4V53v28obay FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES enitiyitemtwo (id))][update entityimage set item_id=? where image_id=?]; SQL [update entityimage set item_id=? where image_id=?]; constraint [null]]

Execution: Trying to save the EnitiyItemOne entity using EnitiyItemOne repo but in the above exception autogenerated query is showing 'REFERENCES enitiyitemtwo (id))', here referencing the wrong table enitiyitemtwo, it should be enitiyitemone table as I am trying to save the EnitiyItemOne entity.

Scenario:

```
public class EntityImage{
@Id
private long image_id;

private String image_path;

private long item_id;
}

public class EnitiyItemOne{
@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
private List<EntityImage> itemImages;
}

public class EnitiyItemTwo{
@Id
private long id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
private List<EntityImage> itemImages;
}
```

Note: item_id is the foreign key, used in the EntityImage table.

Is the above structure possible in the Springboot using the MYSQL Database?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  Here are some documentation that will guide you: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany,_No_Inverse_ManyToOne,_No_Join_Table_(JPA_2.x_ONLY)

Comment: @lane.maxwell. The link you shared same I have tried and working fine, Explaining the issue again: when I try to use OneToMany for EntityImage list in multiple entities it throws exception. but when OneToMany for EntityImage list uses in a single entity then works fine. I will add the exception in the code above for the ref.